# Open Excel files on a remote computer

Tags: ruby, excel, macos

I want to programmatically open Excel files on a user's computer, read what is in the first cell, then save this to a mysql db on my webapp with the following info:

```
cell content (text)
file_updated_date (date)
```

1. Is this possible?
2. Will the user have to install a desktop application for me to open files on their computer, or can I get permission to run a script and return information from a website?
3. What language or technologies are available to open Excel files, read content, and send to an http endpoint? Is this a Ruby program?

Comment: Which Excel version? Is it xsl, or xlsx? The latter is easier.

Comment: If you truly want easy stick with CSV. Excel can export a CSV list no problem and ruby has it's own [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class already. If you want to go that approach there are a multitude of step-throughs for it. If not there is also a way to read from excel it's just...uglier at times.

Comment: Let's do xlsx then, or CSV as a proof of concept. Thanks for the advice guys. So what tutorials should I be looking for? I'm assuming I'll have to make people download a ruby script or "application", that runs on their computer and curls or something to talk to a webserver about what was found on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

[RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) is going to be your friend. Learn it, like it, love it. That link should take your straight to his CSV/Excel importing video that can walk you through basically exactly what you're trying to do. As far as reading from the file goes anyways. As for writing back to the webserver, if the webserver doesn't move you can embed the address into your code and work from that. [HTTPClient](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/frames) should be able to help you with that part.